# How to change URL of Jenkins hosted on AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

Example:
Currently I'm accessing Jenkins on : IP_address:8080
I want to customize the URL and make it available for public use: http:\jenkins-myjob-myproject.com

Any leads for this?
Do I need to set-up a proxy?
I'm totally alien to this. Any suggestions would be really helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe route53 can help you? https://aws.amazon.com/route53/

Answer (score 0):

You could use Route 53 and also attach an Elastic IP to your EC2 instance so its public IP address won't change. Be careful with Elastic IPs because if they are not attached to any instance they'll charge you. Additionally, you could try to use a WebServer like Nginx as reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks! that helped. Using Nginx as reverse proxy.